# How do I remove Bing as the default search engine in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, search

I have Windows 8 and I want to use Google as my default search provider add-on. How can I add GOOGLE as my DEFAULT search provider add-on and DELETE the Bing add-on ? This means that I want GOOGLE to be opened automatically when I search for an information on the internet and not Bing.

Comment: which is your browser ?

Comment: IE->Manage Add-Ons->Search Providers.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. On IE press `Alt+X` or go to Toolbox.
2. Click on **Manage add-ons**.
3. On the Manage add-ons screen click on **"Search Providers"**, then go down to the bottom left and click on **"Find more search providers"**.
4. A new IE will open. Scroll down on the new IE page till you see the different add-ons including Google.
5. Click on it and it will take you to a new page. Click where it says to add the add-on.
6. To set the add-on as default, go to tool box again, click on **"Search Providers"**, select desired add-on and click on **"Set as default"** on the bottom right corner. Close Manage add-ons.

   Done.

Answer (score 0):

By uninstalling the Bing Toolbar, it is no longer the default search engine.  It does not remove to other Bing options embedded within Windows.  If you want to remove it from browsers check this link http://www.pcworld.com/article/249158/how_to_change_your_browsers_default_search_engine.html

Comment: Bing still exists as an ***add-on***. It has nothing to do with the Bing Toolbar. You can see for yourself *Internet Options → Programs tab → Manage Add-On button → Search Providers*. The *Remove* button is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Firefox or Chrome, they both have google as default search engine. If you are using IE, click on the gear wheel (top right corner) and choose Manage Add-on.

Click on Search Provider, and choose "Find more search providers" which will bring you to Microsoft Internet Explorer Addon Gallery - do a search on the site for Google and click "Add to Internet Explorer".

Once added, you check again the "manage add-on" page, and click on Google, and click "Set as Default" and click on the Bing Bar, and remove (if you wish).

And also follow the other answer from malakrsnaslava to uninstall bing toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

WORKING SOLUTION (especially for "Windows 8.1 with Bing")
 Go to: http://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/toolbar/ie/index.html . Click on "Download Google Toolbar". Then be sure you've checked "Set Google as default search in Internet Explorer and notify me of changes". Click on "Accept and Install". Let Google do its thing. Restart IE11. After restart you'll be asked if you want to enable toolbar - you can leave toolbar disabled. Dialog box will pop up to choose Search Provider - obviously choose Google. Then go to: Tools>Manage Add-ons>Search Providers and get rid off Bing if you like. That's it. You're good.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting Bing through the Add-Ons is not possible in 8.0.  All options to remove/disable are greyed out.  The default selection is disabled by MS, and will allow no other provider to be selected.  The idea of switching from Bing to Google is simply selecting a vile twin - no difference.  Selecting from the proferred (yes, that's spelled correctly) list of other "search providers" is a joke.  The Bing search bar does not exist on my computer.  Still, all the above, are problems.  I cannot find the location of a folder or link used to bring up Bing.  So far, I haven't found anything identifiable in the registry to alter or remove.  I looked over the root files and didn't find anything specific.  Once we buy a computer, we should have control of the content.

Comment: Adds absolutely  no value or solution to issue at hand, please leave comments as comments not answers and if you wish to rant do so elsewhere pls.